# Load XMLHttpRequest from facebook Instant game returns empty result, even though I have just saved the data before getting it from server

Tags: xmlhttprequest, fetch, backend, multiplayer, facebook-instant-games

The response from server returns empty result despite just saving data earlier in that contextID with success. Most time it  returns the json data but sometimes in between it returns empty string leading to **createNewGameAsync()** function instead of going directly to **populateFromBackend()** function. I am creating backend from *https://glitch.com/edit/#!/panoramic-tendency* project on glitch.

```
loadData: function () {
    var contextID = FBInstant.context.getID();
    console.log('loadData from ' + contextID);
    FBInstant.player.getSignedPlayerInfoAsync(contextID)
    .then(function (signedPlayerInfo) {
        var url = 'https://panoramic-tendency.glitch.me' + '/get-match'
        var sig = signedPlayerInfo.getSignature();
        var method = 'POST'
        var payload = { 'signature': sig };
        return req(url, method, payload);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        if (result.empty) {
            return this.createNewGameAsync();
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(result.data);
        }
    }.bind(this)).then(function (backendData){  
            this.populateFromBackend(backendData);
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function (error) {
        this.displayError(error);
    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: It mostly happens when Other user is updating the data after turn is over, while this user loads data every next second to detect other's turn is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was saving the FbInstant.Player.getPhoto() url as well in database. During encoding with getSignedPlayerInfoAsync() the signature generated was not valid format, and server couldn't decode it resulting in null value.